# Make a running program that accepts external commands while running

Tags: python

How to create a program that receives commands from another program, while both are running?

My program needs to use some modules, and the modules needs some classes from the main program, but, the program needs to be running, or the functions don't works

I have tried:

main.py:

```
import discord
import command

client = discord.Client()
server = discord.utils.get(client.servers, name='my server')

class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
    def add_role():
        role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name=role)
        client.add_roles(self.user, role)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run('my token')
    command.execute()
```

command.py:

```
import main

def execute():
    #do some stuff and get a user object
    my_user = main.User(user_obj)
    my_user.add_roles('mod')
```

But the add_roles function can't get the server, because client isn't running
and if i put client.run outside main, the client tries to run twice

command.py functions really **needs** to be outside main.py

The solution i have thinked, is to make command.py another process, and send commands to the main.py process, like "ADD ROLE (USER)", which would be useful in other problems i am having

But i have no idea how to implement this

Comment: Creating a separate client to send commands to the server is a perfectly good design. Plenty of servers come with "admin clients" to handle exactly that.

Comment: my_user.add_roles('mod') should be changed with my_user.add_role('mod')

Answer (score 0):

i used rpyc to make a local connection,
something like this:

main.py:

```
class Network(rpyc.Service):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        #Objects to share with modules
        self.User = User

        #Start connection
        conn = ThreadedServer(self, port=10000, protocol_config={"allow_public_attrs": True})
        t = Thread(target=conn.start)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = Network()
```

command.py:

```
conn = rpyc.connect("localhost", 10000)
User = conn.root.User

def execute():
    #do some stuff and get a user object
    my_user = User(user_obj)
    my_user.add_role('mod')
```